# partition table in hive

Tags: hadoop, logging, hive, partition

I have some logs that I processed, then I will store this information in a table in hive. I will partitioned in weeks so in the first week I have 7 files (one per day). Then If I want to know  what do some Person in a day can this partition help me? or not because I don't  search per week

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will help you in that by specifying the week in your WHERE clause you will limit the data searched to a specific week.  You could create a second partition on date (or day of week) that would give you the option to limit to a week or a week/date.  Turning on dynamic partitioning during your loading can make the creation of these partitions much easier.

Answer (score 0):

you can create paritation for day instead of week . That will help a lot while searching for a person on the same day.